# Shell script to find increase in occurance count between two files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

File1.log

```
2000 apple
2333 cat
5343 dog
1500 lion
```

File2.log

```
2500 apple
2333 cat
1700 lion
```

Need a shell script to output as below:

```
500 apple
200 lion
```

Have tried lot of solution but nothing worked out as I'm having both text and string. Could someone help on this. Thanks

EDIT(by RavinderSingh13): Added OP's efforts which OP had shown in comments to in post:

```
#!/bin/bash
input1="./File1.log"
input2="./File2.log"
while IFS= read -r line2
do
  while IFS=read -r line1
  do
     echo "$line1"
  done < "$input1"
  echo "$line2"
done < "$input2"
```

Comment: Are the names unique?

Comment: Also you mentioned `Have tried lot of solution but nothing worked out as I'm having both text and string` so please do add all those efforts in your question in CODE TAGS and let us know then too.

Comment: Yes names are unique on both files

Comment: I had a block of codes to iterate each line in these two files but don't know how to compare the counts which is a numeric value

Comment: @user2170023, My answer is ready but waiting for you to add your efforts into your question, so kindly do so.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
input1="./File1.log"
input2="./File2.log"
while IFS= read -r line2
do
 while IFS=read -r line1
 do
  echo "$line1"
 done < "$input1"
 
 echo "$line2"
done < "$input2"

Comment: @user2170023, Thank you for showing efforts, comments are NOT meant for showing code samples, please add them in your question, request you to edit your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} $2 in a && ($1-a[$2])>0{print $1-a[$2],$2}' file1 file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$1
  next
}
($2 in a) && ($1-a[$2])>0{
  print $1-a[$2],$2
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above solution here.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE once file1 is being read then do following.
  a[$2]=$1                        ##Creating an array a whose index is $2 and value is $1 of current line.
  next                            ##Using next function of awk, to skip all further lines from here.
}                                 ##Closing condition BLOCK for FNR==NR here.
($2 in a) && ($1-a[$2])>0{        ##Checking condition if $2 is present in array a AND difference of $1 and array a with index $2 is greater than 0 then do following.
  print $1-a[$2],$2               ##Printing difference between $1 and array a with index $2 along with current $2 here.
}                                 ##Closing BLOCK for above condition here.
' file1 file2                     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if (!($2 in entry)) { entry[$2]=$1 } else { delta=$1-entry[$2]; if (delta!=0) {print delta,$2} } }' FILE_1 FILE2
```

You can also put this into a file, e.g. `delta.awk`:

```
{
  if (!($2 in entry)) {
    entry[$2]=$1 
  } else { 
    delta=$1-entry[$2]
    if (delta !=0) { # Only output lines of non-zero increment/decrement
      print delta,$2
    } 
  } 
}
```

Invoke via `awk -f delta.awk FILE_1.txt FILE_2.txt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot - works like charm, but I'm bit improvising

Comment: @user2170023 What do you mean by *`I'm bit improvising`*?

Comment: `if(!s[$2])` will fail when `s[$2]` is `0`. ITYM `if(!($2 in s))`. Some white space including newlines and indenting would greatly improve the readability of your script.

Comment: Will add whitespace and indenting. Sorry.